# Firebase Login URL Fetch Config Error

Tags: ios, firebase

I am trying to have my login function for firebase run after updating it, but the function is nil and I am getting the following messages:

`Cannot create a URL to fetch a configuration with empty app instance ID or empty platform (app instance, platform): (nil), ios`

`[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023125] Unable to get configuration. Invalid server URL.`

My code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {
    let email = self._Email.text!
    let password = self._Password.text!
    print("below is the email")
    print(email)
    print("below is the password")
    print(password)

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Successful login")

            if user!.isEmailVerified{
                let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileView") as! ProfileView
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
             } else {
                 print("nil is hitting")
             }
        } else {
            print("Some nil error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like an error in your initialization. Can you show the code of it?

Comment: Given you have followed the guidelines below, setup the GoogleService-Info.plist and pods again. 

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift

Comment: Downvote for vague questioning due to unlimited possibilities . You should elaborate the procedures of setup. Read write permission on Firebase  database  you have configured can also contribute to this issue.